# Ecto association custom name

Tags: associations, elixir, ecto

Is it possible to set a custom name to an association?

For example: I have classical "User -> Posts" situation:

```
create table(:users) do
    add :first_name, :string
    add :last_name, :string

    timestamps()
end

create table(:posts) do
    add :text, :string
    add :user_id, references(:users, on_delete: :nothing)

    timestamps()
end
```

and schema:

```
schema "users" do
  field :first_name, :string
  field :last_name, :string
  has_many :posts, MyProj.Post

  timestamps()
end

schema "posts" do
  field :text, :string
  belongs_to :user, MyProj.User

  timestamps()
end
```

I want the association in `posts` to be called not `user` but `author`.
If I change my schema to:

```
schema "posts" do
  field :text, :string
  belongs_to :author, MyProj.User, [foreign_key: :user_id]

  timestamps()
end
```

I get error: `field 'author' in 'select' does not exist in schema MyProj.Post`

Edited:

I get the error trying to query all posts:

```
def all_posts _root, _args, _info do
  posts_query = from p in Post,
    preload: [:author],
    select: %{
      posted_by: p.author,
      text: p.text
    }

  posts = Repo.all(posts_query)
  {:ok, posts}
end
```

Stack-trace:

```
[info] Sent 500 in 30ms
[error] #PID<0.478.0> running MyProj.Endpoint terminated
Server: localhost:4000 (http)
Request: POST /graphiql
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (Ecto.QueryError) lib/my-proj/resolvers/post_resolver.ex:7: field `author` in `select` does not exist in schema MyProj.Post in query:

from p in MyProj.Post,
  select: %{posted_by: p.author, text: p.text},
  preload: [:author]

        (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/queryable.ex:124: Ecto.Repo.Queryable.execute/5
        (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/queryable.ex:37: Ecto.Repo.Queryable.all/4
        (my-proj) lib/my-proj/resolvers/post_resolver.ex:17: MyProj.PostResolver.all_posts/3
        (absinthe) lib/absinthe/resolution.ex:147: Absinthe.Resolution.call/2
        (absinthe) lib/absinthe/phase/document/execution/resolution.ex:191: Absinthe.Phase.Document.Execution.Resolution.reduce_resolution/1
        (absinthe) lib/absinthe/phase/document/execution/resolution.ex:161: Absinthe.Phase.Document.Execution.Resolution.do_resolve_field/4
        (absinthe) lib/absinthe/phase/document/execution/resolution.ex:147: Absinthe.Phase.Document.Execution.Resolution.do_resolve_fields/6
        (absinthe) lib/absinthe/phase/document/execution/resolution.ex:87: Absinthe.Phase.Document.Execution.Resolution.walk_result/5
        (absinthe) lib/absinthe/phase/document/execution/resolution.ex:57: Absinthe.Phase.Document.Execution.Resolution.perform_resolution/3
        (absinthe) lib/absinthe/phase/document/execution/resolution.ex:25: Absinthe.Phase.Document.Execution.Resolution.resolve_current/3
        (absinthe) lib/absinthe/pipeline.ex:247: Absinthe.Pipeline.run_phase/3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem not in the association's name but in my misunderstanding how does Ecto interpret queries.

Since  entities in queries are rather "DB table" rows then schema struct entities, in

```
select: %{
  posted_by: p.author,
  text: p.text
}
```

Ecto is trying to find a table column called `host`, which doesn't exists. 
In order to "fix" this query I needed to think about it in more "SQL-ish" way:

```
posts_query = from p in Post,
join: author in assoc(p, :author),
select: %{
  posted_by: author,
  text: p.text
}
```